# Densest subgraph : density of an intersection

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering, graph-theory

I found an exercice in my textbook and I can't find the answer :

$G = (V;E)$ an undirected graph.

$H_1 = (V_1;E_1)$ and $H_2 = (V_2;E_2)$ are two densest subgraphs in G, i.e., for any subgraph $H = (V_H;E_H)$ of $G$ it holds that
$\frac{E(H)}{V(H)} \leqslant \frac{E_i}{V_i}$

$\hat{H} = (V_1\cap V_2,E_1\cap E_2)$, i.e. the intersection of $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Can you find a lower bond for the density of $\hat{H}$ ($E_1\cap E_2$ is not empty) ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of densest, $E_1/V_1 = E_2/V_2$ and $E(\hat{H})/V(\hat{H}) = E_1\cap E_2/ V_1\cap V_2$. The easiest lower bound is $\min(E_1,E_2)/\max(V_1,V_2)$.